# Customization of the title slide in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, titles

I'm using `CambridgeUSnew` beamer theme. And I need to add additional information between `author` text and `date` text.

At this point I found only one working solution: add this text into author text, like this

```
\title[]{Title Text}

\author[Author B.C.]{Author B.C. \\
\quad \\
\quad \\
some extra text 1 \\
some extra text 2 \\
\quad \\
some extra text 3
}

\date{date text}
```

But I don't like this solution. Is there any better way to customize title page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your approach with some improvements: 1) Instead of `\quad \\` you can use the optional argument of `\\` to add some vertical space. 2) The `\author` command inserts its argument in the document information fields of the resulting PDF file. This will produce some warnings due to the use of `\\`; to turn off the automatic generation of those entries you can use the `usepdftitle=false` class option:

```
\documentclass[usepdftitle=false]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\title[]{Title Text}
\author[Author B.C.]{Author B.C. \\[2\baselineskip]
some extra text 1 \\
some extra text 2 \\[\baselineskip]
some extra text 3
}
\date{date text}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Another possibility would be to use some of the predefined fields that go into the title page frame; for example, if not used, you could write the additional information in the `\institution` field, which writes the information between the author and the date:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\title[]{Title Text}
\author[Author B.C.]{Author B.C.}
\institute[]{\normalsize some extra text 1\\
some extra text 2 \\[\baselineskip]
some extra text 3
}
\date{date text}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

i wanted to add just a comment to Gonzalo's answer, but i think i don't have enough points.

instead of using `usepdftitle=false` you can do something like

```
\author{\texorpdfstring{your long title \\ with breaklines}{title for pdf}}
```

a complete solution would involve modifying the titlepage of the frame.

Comment: +1 for *a complete solution would involve modifying the titlepage of the frame*.